# Change the speed of Google Translate speech

Tags: google-translate

Is there any way to regulate the speed of spoken words in Google Translator? I find it a bit slow and have looked to see if there is a setting, but I have found nothing.

Comment: it takes me about half a second to translate a paragraph of 80 words. Maybe you need to 'regulate' your internet connection?

Comment: Thanx, but there is nothing wrong with my internet connection.  It is high speed. I'm talking about the spoken words. Not the time it takes to translate a phrase.

Comment: Oh. I didn't even know that's offered.

Answer (score 3):

There is no setting to permanently change the playback speed. As you likely already know, they play the normal speed on the first click, the slower speed on the second click, and then alternate on subsequent clicks.

If the normal speed is too slow for you then you are unfortunately out of luck. If it's tolerable then I'm confident there is a way to create a custom web browser script that will force it to always play the normal speed. If that interests you then check out [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox. Note that this is just an addon to run custom scripts. You would need to make your own Google Translate script or find an existing one.

Comment: Good grief! I'm sorry I asked. If I knew how to create a script do you think I would've come here asking the question?   -End of discussion.

Comment: @Ella try shifting your perspective. Now you know you can script things to customize websites. If you spend some time learning it then you can figure out a solution instead of acting like the world owes you something. End of discussion indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the speed of HTML5 video/audio with

```
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = < speed >;
```

with speed ranging from 0.5 to 2

to get the proper URL where the video is, check the developer tools > network and look for the network request with the type media (play audio first). then post the code above in the console and change the speed.

This works for me in Chrome, but I'm sure there must be an easier way.

Comment: you could put this in a script for tamper monkey or something

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Userscript using TamperMonkey.

Remove all existing code from the script, then add the following:

```
Gv.prototype.play = function() {
    if (this.b != this.K || this.g != this.H || this.c != this.I) {
        if (this.m)
            var a = [this.b];
        else {
            a = Ev[Fv[this.g.toLowerCase()]];
            var b = []
              , c = this.X
              , d = this.b.replace(/[ \u3000\n\r\t\s]+/g, " ");
            Av(b, d, a, z(c.a, c), z(c.g, c));
            a = b
        }
        b = [];
        c = [];
        d = "";
        null != this.L && (d += "&" + this.L);
        null != this.v ? d += "&ttsspeed=" + this.v : 0 != this.c && (d += "&ttsspeed=" + this.c);
        this.o && (d += "&hint=" + this.o);
        for (var e = 0; e < a.length; e++)
            b.push(Hv(this, a[e], this.g, a.length, e, d)),
            c.push(a[e].length);
        this.a.set(b, this.b.length, c, {
            textlen: this.b.length,
            tl: this.g
        });
        this.K = this.b;
        this.H = this.g;
        this.I = this.c
    }
    this.a.start();
    this.T && (this.c = 0 == this.c ? 0 : 0)
}
;
```

No idea how long this solution will last. I'm sure Google will change something eventually. It works by overriding the existing play function with the flipping mechanism removed (it will always play at regular speed).

Answer (score -1):

Google has a text-to-speech application with speed control that can be used at https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/